# Find the maximum of $g(ξ)=(e^{πξi}-1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_ke^{2πξik}$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $\xi\in\mathbb R$, $n\in\mathbb N$, $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^n\in\mathbb R$. I wonder if it is possible to calculate or estimate the maximum of $|g(\xi)|$, where
$$g(\xi)=(e^{\pi \xi i}-1)\sum_{k=0}^n a_k e^{2\pi \xi i k}\, .$$
My attempt:
$$\max_\xi|g(\xi)|\leq \max_\xi\left|e^{\pi \xi i}-1\right|\, \max_\xi\left|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k e^{2\pi \xi i k}\right|\leq \max_\xi\left|e^{\pi \xi i}-1\right|\, \sum_{k=0}^n \left|a_k \right|\, .$$
Can we do better?

Comment: If $a_k$'s are all positive, then $\lvert g(1)\rvert=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$. So I doubt you can do better...

Comment: Did you mean to say $\{a_k\}_{k = 0}^n \in \Bbb R$ in the first line?

Comment: Guess you did!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Yes, I have edited my post. Thanks